# VLC Audio won't play unless it's a certain headphone (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10, vlc-media-player

I usually watch my videos using bluetooth headphones. When I try to play audio on VLC with any other audio device that is not the bluetooth headphones, it doesn't work. This only happens to VLC, I can watch other videos on the web with other headphones or without headphones just fine. I already check the audio devices, and it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple solutions online that should work.

1. Go into settings and press 'reset preferences' down the bottom.
2. Open the control panel, click on the Sound Option, and Windows will say "Enhancements for this audio device are causing problems" -  "Disable"
3. Open VLC > tools> preferences>audio > output module select waveout audio output> select speakers - Save.

Hope this helps,

I found these solutions on this forum:

http://ccm.net/forum/affich-689197-vlc-video-player-suddenly-has-no-sound

Comment: Nothing worked, I even tried some of the solutions from the forum, but to no avail. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

VLC doesn't like swapping audio device while it's running, even if you use a switcher app like [AudioSwitcher](http://audioswit.ch/er) - freeware, which I would highly recommend [no affiliation].

The solution is to quit, change outputs, launch.